# Logic problem using global variables as flags in python

Tags: python, global, flags

I am having a problem trying to use a global variable as a flag to determine a condition for a function.
I am just starting to learn Python and it's been several years since a used C/C++.

The simplified code is as follows (I don't post the rest of the code because I think that the problem is within these sections, and probably it is a dumb one):

```
def func1():
    global flag1
    global flag2
    
    if flag1 or flag2:
        if flag1:
            'do something'
            return x
        elif flag2:
            'do something'
            return X
        else:
            pass
    else:
        if 'condition_1 is met':
            flag1 = True        
            'do something'
            return x
        elif 'condition_2 is met':
            flag2 = True
            'do something'
            return x
        else:
            pass


def func2():
    func1()
    window.after(100, func1)


if __name__=='__main__':
    flag1 = False
    flag2 = False
```

'func2' is always running, therefore 'func1' is also always running because it is called from inside 'func2'.

The error I get is "using flag1 and flag2 variables before assignment", and I think it's because I am trying to change the flags values inside the 'if' statement, but I can't think of another logic solution for this one.

Like I said, it is probably a dumb error and there is a simple solution, so I will be more than thankfull if somebody can help me.

Comment: Please make this code into an actual [mre].

Comment: As far as I can tell, neither func1 nor func2 are executed here at all.

Comment: Please show more of the code, in particular when do you actually call (not define) `func1` and `func2`, in particular relative to assigning the `flag` variables in the `main` block?

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  Post your MRE; your given code fails in several respects, leaving us to guess at missing definitions and intended functionality.  In particular, the code does not produce the error you claim (and failed to include in full).

Comment: Also note that a global variable is a red flag of poor system design.  Use the parameter and returns values for structured communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replys. Trying to make a minimal reproducible example I detected that there is nothing wrong with the logic of my script, but I have to dig deeper to find the problem.
Sorry for the inconvenience.
This answer can be closed.